# nodejs exec ffmpeg, callback is fired before ffmpeg finishes

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I run ffmpeg command via a nodejs script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('ffmpeg -with -some -options somefile.mp4',function(error, stdout, stderr){
   // some processing 
});
```

I've noticed that sometimes, the callback is fired even before ffmpeg finishes. How can I make sure to do the callback processing only after ffmpeg finishes? and what may have caused it to fire the callback without finishing?

Comment: Look at what's inside stderr, most probably there was an error and ffmpeg exited instantly.

Comment: It didn't. I can see it working with ps. and I can see it's output keep growing.

Comment: What happens when you try using execSync?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *exec* use *process.spawn*. You can then have callbacks for different events.

```
this.ffmpeg = process.spawn("ffmpeg",
   "-f dshow -some -other -options somefile.mp4".split(" "),
    { shell: true })

this.ffmpeg.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("ffmpeg error: " + error)
})

this.ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
})

this.ffmpeg.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log("ffmpeg shutdown: code " + code + ", signal " + signal)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach

```
downloadHLS = function (uri, opath) {
      var self = this;

      // defaults
      var loglevel = self.logger.isDebug() ? 'debug' : 'warning';
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const args = [
          '-y',
          '-loglevel', loglevel,
          '-v', 'quiet',
          '-i', uri,
          opath
        ];
        const opts = {
          cwd: self._options.tempDir
        };
        cp.spawn('ffmpeg', args, opts)
          .stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            self.logger.warn(`stderr: ${data}`);
          })
          .on('message', msg => self.logger.info(msg))
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('exit', (code, signal) => {
            self.logger.info("downloadHLS [exit] code:%s signal:%s", code, signal);
          })
          .on('close', () => {
            self.logger.info("downloadHLS [close]");
             return resolve();
          })
      });
    }//downloadHLS
```

The event called when `ffpmeg` ends the processing is `close`. The event `exit` is not being called in this modality actually.